# Prolog: for what terms t does the evaluation of the goal p(t) terminate and which does it not?

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

Consider the following logic program:

```
p(b) :- p(b).
p(X) :- r(b).
p(a) :- p(a).
r(Y).
```

For what terms t does the evaluation of the goal p(t) terminate and which does it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to determine all the queries that do not terminate. And I assume you mean terminate universally. That is, we are not only looking at the first answer, but we look at *all* of them.

There is a very quick answer to this, provided your program is pure, monotonic: Simply take the **most general query**. That is, if there is any possibility for any term `T` to make `p(T)` not terminating, then `p(X)` will be non-terminating too.

If we want to known more, we have to look closer. With a [failure-slice](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/failure-slice) we may narrow down actual reasons for non-termination.  By inserting goals **`false`** into your program, we are reducing the number of inferences that are possible for a query. But if the remaining program still permits infinitely many inferences, we have found a loop. In this case:

```
p(b) :- false, p(b).
p(X) :- false, r(b).
p(a) :- p(a), false.

r(Y) :- false.
```

Is one minimal failure-slice. That is, `p(a)` will not terminate. Beware, however, that
simply querying `p(a)` (in your original program) will succeed, you need to insist to look at further answers:

```
?- p(a).
   true    % there is one answer
;  loops.  % loops "on backtracking"
```

To save you the labor of asking for further answers, simply use `p(a), false` instead.

There is another minimal failure-slice:

```
p(b) :- p(b), false.
p(X) :- false, r(b).
p(a) :- false, p(a).

r(Y) :- false.
```

See [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) for more examples.

Comment: Your mention of most general query is exactly the path I was on, but was unsure of "science" behind it. Also, through testing I found those same queries non-terminating but didn't know the reason why. Prolog seems pretty cool. Thank for the help!